# how to create association between classes in Protege?

Tags: ontology, protege4, manchester-syntax

I have a sensor class, Input class which is the subclass of Process class and a SensingData class. I want to associate the Input class to the sensing data class saying that input is the sensing data. can i do it by creating an object property hasData like inupt hasData SensingData? or do i have to use the annotation property??

Answer (score 0):

You can create `hasData` as an object property with domain `Input` and range `SensingData`.

Comment: no i have process class which has two sub classes input and output and sensing data and sensor  is a different class.